# consul: skipping self join check

Tags: docker-compose, consul

I am new using Docker and I am following the electronic armory example where jHipster is used to run a consul container with the command:

```
$docker-compose -f src/main/docker/consul.yml up.
```

Consul keeps on trying to do a self join check but complains about a small cluster. I am running Windows 7. How can I solve this. All searches do not address this particular case.

```
     Node name: '9f7a73b07398'
    Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
        Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
   Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
  Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
       Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false

2017-10-26T23:02:51.993596769Z ==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
2017-10-26T23:02:51.993718823Z 
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [DEBUG] Using random ID "733ef85e-dcb1-503d-b165-699098b15266" as node ID
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] raft: Initial configuration (index=1): [{Suffrage:Voter ID:127.0.0.1:8300 Address:127.0.0.1:8300}]
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 9f7a73b07398.dc1 127.0.0.1
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] raft: Node at 127.0.0.1:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state (Leader: "")
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 9f7a73b07398 127.0.0.1
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] consul: Adding LAN server 9f7a73b07398 (Addr: tcp/127.0.0.1:8300) (DC: dc1)
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] consul: Handled member-join event for server "9f7a73b07398.dc1" in area "wan"
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 0.0.0.0:8600 (tcp)
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 0.0.0.0:8600 (udp)
2017/10/26 23:02:51 [INFO] agent: Started HTTP server on [::]:8500
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout from "" reached, starting election
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [INFO] raft: Node at 127.0.0.1:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state in term 2
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [DEBUG] raft: Votes needed: 1
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [DEBUG] raft: Vote granted from 127.0.0.1:8300 in term 2. Tally: 1
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 1
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [INFO] raft: Node at 127.0.0.1:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
2017/10/26 23:02:52 [DEBUG] consul: Skipping self join check for "9f7a73b07398" since the cluster is too small
```

Comment: You should format your questions in order to be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Anastasios for the help, much appreciated.